# Insertion Sort in Python3.6

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, insertion-sort

Can this insertion sort program be improved in any way? Please suggest something in terms of efficiency and lines of code as well.

```
def insort(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        l = i + 1
        for j in range(l, -1, -1):
            print(j)
            if j == 0:
                break
            if lst[j] < lst[j-1]:
                lst[j], lst[j-1] = lst[j-1], lst[j]
    return lst

data = input("Enter the numbers separated by spaces: ")

print(insort(list(map(int, data.split()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. It's simple and easy to read. The only nit I might have:

```
l = i + 1
for j in range(l, -1, -1):
```

could be:

```
for j in range(i + 1, -1, -1):
```

since it doesn't look like you're using `l` anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll keep this in mind while coding similar problems. Have a good day!